# Error No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored

Tags: android-studio, build.gradle

despues de compilar mi archivo gradle me marca los siguientes errores:

> Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.
>
> Error:(4) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'.

Este es mi archivo gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.discomsc.eqbe"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/java'
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1'
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    //compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

La verdad no se porque marca error si estaba funcionando correctamente.

Comment: Agregegaste : compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)' ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con respecto al problema:

> Error No resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored

Se esta requiriendo un recurso que no se encuentra en la versión del SDK,  te sugiero configurar a las últimas versiones no menor a 25 por ejemplo:

```
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
```

y

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
```

Comment: gracias ya funciono

Comment: Excelente @user4028047 Saludos!